# Ip телефония для сайта

Tags: php, телефония

Стала интересна реализация просмотра информации по звонкам на сайте, но не где не могу найти информации на эту тему

Есть небольшая самописная cms и ip телефон

Например как на сайте показать последний звонок или как записывать все звонки.(Например как на amocrm)

С ip- телефонией работаю в первые, буду рад любой информации/материалу

Как я понял можно просто подключить номер например к АТС [onPBX](https://www.onlinepbx.ru/) и сделать через api интеграцию в свою cms.

Как устроены эти АТС. Как самому отлавливать звонки? без использования сторонних

Связался с оператором, дали доступ к `Asterisk`

Не могу найти, как на `Asterisk` добавить нового пользователя, как их настроить. Есть только с web интерфейсом freePBX, но на сервере он не стоит

Comment: посмотрите в сторону Asterisk. Все звонки пишите в базу, а там уже что хотите то и делайте с этими данными.